# CSS: Turn Overflow Items into New Row

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

I just bought a WP theme: http://demo.wpzoom.com/evertis/ and I want to modify the "Featured Articles" section.

Instead of using the scroll button to view all featured articles, I want to display all featured articles (ie. every three articles on one row).

I try to modify the CSS but can not get what I want. Most "overflow" articles are about texts.

```
     .scrollable {

    /* required settings */

    position:relative;

    overflow:hidden;

    width: 930px;

    height:400px;

}
 .slide {

 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

 -khtml-border-radius: 5px; 

 -moz-border-radius: 5px;

 border-radius: 5px;

 background:#e6eef4;

 padding:10px;

 margin:0 20px 0 0;

 float:left;

 width:270px;

 position:relative;

 display:inline;

 }
```

I use Firebug on Firefox and tried different combinations of "display:block" and "float:auto", but can not get what I want exactly. I can only make it display one article one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging in/adding this CSS will do it:

```css
#thumbs {
    width: auto;
    position: static;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scrollable {
    overflow: visible;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is magic! Your code works like charm! When I first saw your answer, I seriously doubt it will work because you even didnt change the “height:400px;” and "float:left". How can that be? I read somewhere that "float:left" and "display:inline" mainly responsible for these kind of stuff. How can your code work even you didnt change “height:400px;” in ".scrollable"?

Comment: It didn't matter because `#featured` saved the day - it has `float: left` so it contained the floats. I've edited my answer to something that should look identical, but makes more sense.